Rank-Nullity Theorem does not hold when non-pivot columns are linearly dependent?
Definitions:
Let A be an m X n matrix.
Rank-Nullity Theorem states that:
$$
Rank(A) + Nullity(A) = n
$$
Counter-Example:
Let's see a matrix where the solution space is a line:
Let A be in reduced row-echelon form with 3 pivot columns and 2 non-pivot columns. The 2 non-pivot columns (4 and 5) are linearly dependent, for instance:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
Let $C_4$ and $C_5$ be columns 4 and 5 of A, respectively. $X$ is the null space. Then
$$
C_5 = kC_4, \text{where k is any Real (linear dependence)}\
$$
$$
X = - C_4 * x_4 - C_5 * x_5
$$
$$
 =- C_4 * (x_4 + k*x_5)
$$
C_4 is the only direction vector in the solution. A plane requires two direction vectors. Therefore, the solution spans a line. Hence, Nullity(A) = 1 ?
But then Rank-Nullity Theorem does not hold.
Attaching Geogebra link + screnshot:
https://www.geogebra.org/classic/xmm6yd6g
Non-pivot columns linear dependent:

Non-pivot columns linear independent:

I've just begun learning linear algebra, so, please, explain simply.

Shouldn't it be $3+2=5$? @DietrichBurde

Your nullity is $2$, and your rank is $3$

If you are computing the Left-nullity, then you have Nullity 0 and rank 3, but in that case they have to sum up to 3 so it is also correct

The nullspace will be in $\mathbb{R}^5$, not in $\mathbb{R}^3$. You've found $X$ by taking linear combinations of the columns which are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so the vector you've found is not in the nullspace.

@CyclotomicField's comment helped me spot my error, thank you!

The rank of $A$ is $3$, clearly. On the other hand, if $v=(a,b,c,d,e)$ is such that $A.v=0$, then$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a+d+e=0\\b+d+e=0\\c+d+e=0.\end{array}\right.\iff a=b=c=-d-e.$$So, $X$ is spanned by the linearly independent vectors $(-1,-1,-1,1,0)$ and $(-1,-1,-1,0,1)$, and therefore $\operatorname{null}(A)=2$. Since $3+2=5$, there is no contradiction.

perhaps it's worth it to mention the mistake in the original solution, namely that the 4th and the 5th element of the solution vector were "forgotten".

as an extra comment, plotting (a,b,c) would still look like a line, but the solution is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^5$

@YordanGrigorov would you mind adding the correction directly in the original post so that newcomers to the post are able to read it correctly?

@Croco, I understand the value of updating original posts, but in this case, the counter-example would not be a counter example and I might just as well delete the post if we're going in this direction.
